# Greens Theorem for periodic functions

Tags: solid-state-physics, mathematics, crystals, greens-functions

Ashcroft and Mermin supply the following proof of their equations (I.1/2), which get used often in computing integrals over the first Brillouin zone (in computing current densities etc.).

I find myself unable to follow their step noted just below (I.8). They say "We can apply (I.1) to the last term in (I.8), taking the two periodic functions in (I.1) to be $v$ [from (I.8)] and the various components of the gradient of $u$ [[from (I.8)]". I have two questions about this:

1. (I.1) is a vector identity, whereas this term is scalar in nature. I suppose I can argue that (I.1) must hold component-wise and so extract the corresponding scalar identity?
2. More importantly, I must use that the gradient of $u$ is itself $\mathbf{R}$-periodic if $u$ is. Is this so? Is the derivative of a periodic function periodic necessarily?

[image]

Comment: Concerning your second question, I think this is easy to prove from the definition of the derivative. In 1D, if $a$ is the period you have$$\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} = \frac{f(x+a+h)-f(x+a)}{h}$$ for all $x$ and $h\neq0$ by the definition of periodicity, and so the limits as $h \to 0$ must be the same as well (if they exist).

Comment: Oof -- thank you! @MichaelSeifert